# How to import data from multiple sheets into one sheet with BYROW and LAMBDA?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with various tabs. Each tab has the same column header in A1 and similar data (same format) in column A.
In "sheet2" I have a list of all the tab names in Column A.
I wish to combine all the data for all tab's row A into "sheet2" in column B.

I have managed to get the desired result using...
`=ARRAYFORMULA({indirect(A1&"!A2:A"&COUNTA(indirect(A1&"!A:A")));indirect(A2&"!A2:A"&COUNTA(indirect(A2&"!A:A")))})`

However, this only covers 2 tabs, and I have about 50 tabs to add, with more tabs added regularly.

So I wish to try and use a `QUERY` formula, which was recommended to me.
I have run a few versions, see below, but the resulting output is 5 rows of

> #VALUE!

BYROW and LAMBDA are new to me and I am uncertain on what I am doing wrong.

```
=QUERY(BYROW(A1:A5,LAMBDA(x, INDIRECT(x&"!A2:A6")))))

=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(BYROW(A1:A5,LAMBDA(x, INDIRECT(x&"!A2:A6"))))})
```

Below is 2 samples of the tabs where the data is stored, each tab is names after the Product Type, so EE and EX in this sample, and those same tab names are used in the third table (below).

| Product Code |
| --- |
| EE220123 |
| EE190223 |
| EE260323 |
| EE030423 |
| EE090423 |
| EE170423 |
| EE230423 |
| EE010523 |
| EE070523 |
| EE150523 |
| EE210523 |
| EE280523 |

| Product Code |
| --- |
| EX040423 |
| EX250423 |
| EX160523 |
| EX060623 |
| EX270623 |
| EX180723 |
| EX080823 |
| EX290823 |
| EX190923 |
| EX101023 |

This is my "sheet2"

| Product Type |
| --- |
| EE |
| EX |
| EJ |
| GB |
| GBIR |

This is the sample sheet I am working on, columns F, G and H contain my recent attempt, it is Column H which I wish to get working.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gvOZ_GuZx6HOLHQ7WwyIlFHrAihoNXz2ysZkublh7Fs/edit#gid=1077440502

Expected Outcome table

| Product Type | Product Code |
| --- | --- |
| EE | EE220123 |
| EX | EE190223 |
| EJ | EE260323 |
| GB | EE030423 |
| GBIR | EE090423 |
| GBIR | EE170423 |
|  | EE230423 |
|  | EE010523 |
|  | EE070523 |
|  | EE150523 |
|  | EE210523 |
|  | EE280523 |
|  | EE290523 |
|  | EX040423 |
|  | EX250423 |
|  | EX160523 |
|  | EX060623 |
|  | EX270623 |
|  | EX180723 |
|  | EX080823 |
|  | EX290823 |
|  | EX190923 |
|  | EX101023 |
|  | EJ240323 |
|  | EJ070423 |
|  | EJ210423 |
|  | EJ050523 |
|  | EJ190523 |
|  | EJ020623 |
|  | EJ160623 |
|  | EJ300623 |
|  | EJ140723 |
|  | EJ280723 |
|  | EJ110823 |
|  | EJ250823 |
|  | EJ080923 |
|  | EJ220923 |
|  | EJ061023 |
|  | EJ201023 |
|  | EJ221223 |
|  | GB050323 |
|  | GB020423 |
|  | GB160423 |
|  | GB300423 |
|  | GB070523 |
|  | GB140523 |
|  | GB210523 |
|  | GB280523 |
|  | GB040623 |
|  | GB110623 |
|  | GB180623 |
|  | GB250623 |
|  | GB020723 |
|  | GB090723 |
|  | GB160723 |
|  | GB230723 |
|  | GB300723 |
|  | GB060823 |
|  | GB130823 |
|  | GB200823 |
|  | GB030923 |
|  | GB100923 |
|  | GB170923 |
|  | GB240923 |
|  | GB011023 |
|  | GB151023 |
|  | GB291023 |
|  | GBIR080423 |
|  | GBIR060523 |
|  | GBIR200523 |
|  | GBIR030623 |
|  | GBIR170623 |
|  | GBIR010723 |
|  | GBIR150723 |
|  | GBIR290723 |
|  | GBIR120823 |
|  | GBIR260823 |
|  | GBIR090923 |
|  | GBIR230923 |
|  | GBIR071023 |
|  | GBIR211023 |
|  | GBIR221223 |

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster I have added tables. Thank you for your help.
Does it help explain my question further?

Comment: Could you add expected output table for the given sample?

Comment: @TheMaster I have added the expected output table - apologies for its length.
As you tab see in column A, there are 5 tabs in my sample, I have not shared all the 5 tabs above, just the EE and EX, however in the outcome table I have added all the product code data from all 5 tabs. 
In my actual spreadsheet, there is about 80 tabs worth of data I wish to array into one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `BYROW`, `REDUCE` supports nested arrays. You can use it to loop through `A2:A6` of Sheet2 and add arrays from other sheets using array literals `{;}`

```
=REDUCE("Product Code", A2:A6, LAMBDA(a,c,{a;indirect(c&"!A2:A"&COUNTA(indirect(c&"!A:A")))}))
```

Comment: thank you @themaster for introducing me to REDUCE. This has worked well.